# Mapping, aggregating and composing totals using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, aggregation, composition

I'm trying to recreate a process to create a list of objects that are an aggregation of another list of objects using Java 8 Streams.

for example, I have a class, described below, that is provided from a database call or similar

```
public class Order {

    private String orderNumber;        
    private String customerNumber;
    private String customerGroup;
    private Date deliveryDate;
    private double orderValue;
    private double orderQty;
}
```

Elsewhere in my application I have a class OrderTotal which represents and aggregation of Order grouping by customer number and group and summing the totals of orderValue and orderQty. (With an equals and hashcode on customerGroup and customerNumber)

```
public class OrderTotal {

    private String customerGroup;
    private String customerNumber;
    private double totalValue;
    private double totalQty;
}
```

The 'long hand' way we have achieved this prior to java 8 is as follows

```
public Collection<OrderTotal> getTotals(List<Order> orders) {
    ///map created for quick access to the order total for each order 
    Map<OrderTotal, OrderTotal> map = new HashMap<>();
    ///loop through all orders adding to the relevaent order total per iteration
    for (Order order : orders) {
        OrderTotal orderTotal = createFromOrder(order);
        {
            ///if the order total already exists in the map use that one, otherwise add it to the map.
            OrderTotal temp = map.get(orderTotal);
            if(temp == null){
                map.put(orderTotal, orderTotal);
            }else{
                orderTotal = temp;
            }
        }
        ///add the values to the total 
        aggregate(orderTotal, order);
    }        
    return map.values();
}

private OrderTotal createFromOrder(Order order) {
    OrderTotal orderTotal = new OrderTotal();
    orderTotal.setCustomerGroup(order.getCustomerGroup());
    orderTotal.setCustomerNumber(order.getCustomerNumber());
    return orderTotal;
}

private void aggregate(OrderTotal orderTotal, Order order){
    orderTotal.setTotalQty(orderTotal.getTotalQty() + order.getOrderQty());
    orderTotal.setTotalValue(orderTotal.getTotalValue() + order.getOrderValue());
}
```

Ive been looking at Collectors using a grouping by and reduction functions but they all seem focused on aggregating the order class rather than composing the totals in the OrderTotal class.

I'm looking for a tidy stream or collect function that removes all the bloat from this code.

Comment: what you are looking for is sum `totalValue` and `totalQty` from Orders and put those into a `OrderTotal` - this is fairly trivial with two streams

Comment: This *may* be a good fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) but be sure to read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first before posting to be sure that it's on topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `toMap` collector as follows:

```
Collection<OrderTotal> result = orders.stream()
            .map(o -> createFromOrder(o))
            .collect(toMap(Function.identity(),
                        Function.identity(),
                        (l, r) -> {
                            aggregate(l, r);
                            return l;
                        }))
                .values();
```

Note that this requires changing the `aggregate` method parameters to `aggregate(OrderTotal orderTotal, OrderTotal order){ ... }` i.e. both parameters are of type `OrderTotal`.

or you could remove the `aggregate` method entirely and perform the logic in the `toMap`:

```
Collection<OrderTotal> result = orders.stream()
            .map(o -> createFromOrder(o))
            .collect(toMap(Function.identity(),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (l, r) -> {
                        l.setTotalQty(l.getTotalQty() + r.getTotalQty());
                        l.setTotalValue(l.getTotalValue() + r.getTotalValue());
                        return l;
                    }))
            .values();
```

Comment: took the liberty to edit the second one, and yes 1+ & welcome back

Comment: actually, I think the OP might want to group by function.identity. btw thanks for the edit.

Comment: minor note that `hashCode` is somehow a bit different, though a customeName is pretty darn unique to me...

Comment: be careful as the OP says `OrderTotal`overrides equals/hashCode, _not_ `Order`

Comment: @Eugene I see..., think I've cracked it now after looking at the code and the task description.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. Im still working through your solution but in answer to the question regarding the identity of the object; the same customerNumber may have a different customerGroup per instance of Order. i.e. a customer can change group over time. Im looking for the mapping to respect the equals and hashcode of the OrderTotal. Thanks!

Comment: @user2936416 note that I've edited the post since... the updated approach should do what your `getTotals` method is doing.

Comment: excellent answer, thanks very much. My only extra step was to amend the createFromOrder method to set the values of totalQty and totalValue from the order.

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this -

```
Double totalQtyAgg =  orders.stream()
                            .map(x -> createFromOrder(x))
                            .mapToDouble(x -> x.totalQty)
                            .sum();
Double totalValueAgg = orders.stream()
                             .map(x -> createFromOrder(x))
                             .mapToDouble(x -> x.totalValue)
                             .sum();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This will giver me the totals for all orders but I am looking for the totals per combination of customerGroup and customerNumber